# Python function to reverse a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

Could anyone please help me to look at what's wrong with the code here?

In order to achieve this:
Define a function that inputs the head node of a linked list, reverses the list and outputs the head node of the reversed list.

Example:
Input: 1->2->3->4->5->NULL
Output: 5->4->3->2->1->NULL

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val: int = val
        self.next: Optional[ListNode] = None

class Solution(object):
    def reverseList(self, head):
        if not head:
            return None
        l = []
        while head:
            l.append(head.val)
            head = head.next
        l = l[::-1]
        hn = ListNode(l[0]) 
        for i in range(1, len(l)):
            hn.next = ListNode(l[i])
            nnext = hn.next
            hn = nnext
        return hn
```

It only returns a single value, what if I want it to output the whole list?
Thank you for your attention and any help with coding/concept/logic would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `return hn` is *inside* your `for` loop. That means the `for` loop only gets one iteration and your method ends.

Comment: Hi sry I just edited, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I see you've edited the code to have the `return hn` outside the `for` loop. So what is the symptom now?

Comment: Now it only returns "[1]", which should be "[5,4,3,2,1]" instead

Comment: Yes, you reverse a list of the values, build a new linked list and return the last `ListNode`. Did you mean to have something like: `first = hn` before the `for` loop and `return first` after?

Comment: You say the requirement is *"...and outputs the head node of the reversed list."* Based on that, returning a single node should be OK?

Comment: I agree the instruction is quite confusing, I suppose the outcome show be the whole reversed linked list

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Python list kinda defeats the purpose of working with linked lists.  you should try to achieve this only by manipulating links between nodes.

For example:

```
def reverseList(head):
    tail = None
    while head:
        head.next, tail, head = tail, head, head.next
    return tail
```

If you're going to use a Python list, first fill it with the nodes. Then link each node to the previous one in the list.  Finally, return the last node in the list:

```
def reverseList(head):
    nodes = [None]
    while head:
        nodes.append(head)
        head = head.next
    for i,previous in enumerate(nodes[:-1],1):
        nodes[i].next = previous
    return nodes[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your code is that in creating a new list you start with:

`hn = ListNode(l[0])`

but inside the loop you lose track of that first node by overwriting `hn`:

`hn = nnext`

Finally when you `return hn` you are referencing the final `ListNode` created.

Comment: I see, but how should I modify the code 

Comment: Oh I know how to do that, I added 'base = hn' above the for loop and changed 'hn' to 'base' inside the loop